# Inserting frames into time line

Tags: animation, keyframes

I want to insert 20 frames into the beginning of the animation so that I can make adjustments. Is there anyway to do this or do I need to shift every object that I have animated over 20 frames? Thanks!

On the time line there appears to be negative frames but I can't access those is there anyway I could start my animation at the -20th frame? That would solve my problem

Answer (score 10):

Go into the *Dope Sheet* and select all your keyframes (<kbd>A</kbd>), then move them 20 frames (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>20</kbd>).

The *Dope Sheet*:
[image]

Comment: If you found this answered your question, please mark it a accepted.

Comment: Well.. I can't find this on the wiki, but can Ctrl+LMB to one side of the current frame (green line) to select all frames on that side and deselect all on the opposite side.
The current frame green line is in fact a pivot.

Answer (score 3):

This works very well when all elements are visible, but some may come into play at a later stage in the timeline, so better push the little ghost-button at the bottom to make them all visible. Else you'll mess up the time line, as I've discovered :-). Can be fixed quite easy, but better prevent that.